# Handling Unknown Factor Levels in R GLM

Tags: r, glm

I have a dataset contained in dataframe `daf` which I am splitting into training and test data based on the date e.g. train on dates below `20090000` and test on dates above. To do this, we split the original dataframe into `daf_train` and `daf_test`.

I am using `GLM` and have a factor in the model `daf$city`. The issue that is arising is that `daf_test` sometimes contains a new city that was not seen in `daf_train`.

I am thinking the best way around this is to do something like

```
levels(daf_train$city) = levels(daf$city)
```

to prewarn it about all possible cities.

I would then like the `GLM` to recognise that for cities that have not been seen before, take an average of the factor coefficients for cities. If all the previous factors' coefficients had mean zero I think this would be good enough.

How would I alter the code to do this

```
mylogit = glm(Y ~ X + factor(city), data=daf_train, family=binomial(link='logit'))
predictions = predict(mylogit, daf_test, type='response')
```

Note, a really ugly and non general way to do this (I am also fairly new to R so maybe this will also mess with the GLM object) is

```
cityLevels = levels(factor(daf$city))
daf_train$city = factor(daf_train$city, cityLevels)

# daf_train$city now has all the levels of the overall dataset 
# But if we train a GLM now, it will ignore any levels without observations

# Instead we split the factor into binary variables
train_data = cbind(daf_train, model.matrix( ~ 0 + city, daf_train))
# Remove the factor variable
train_data$city = NULL

# Now train the GLM
mylogit = glm(Y ~., data = train_data, family=binomial(link='logit'))

# This gives us coefficient values for all factors in the training set
# Any factors not in the training set get coefficient values of NA

# Finally we must convert the factor coefficients to have zero mean
offset = mean(mylogit$coefficients[-1:-34])
mylogit$coefficients[-1:-34] = mylogit$coefficients[-1:-34] - offset
mylogit$coefficients[1] = mylogit$coefficients[1] + offset

# Yeuch, this required us to know where in our coefficients vector our cities started (34)
```

Comment: Not sure that you'll solve the problem if you use the "level" function as you described. I think that the model will not produce any coefficients for the levels that are not included in your train set. I've solved this problem in the past by using (carefully) a nice stratified sampling based on the levels of that variable. In that way all levels are included in both test and train set.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand but in my case I wouldn't want a new city in the test set to ever be seen by the GLM. I just want it to know that if it sees a new city, assign a zero to all factors.

Comment: For example, if you had three cities in the training set with glm parameter estimates 0 (default), 0.1, -0.4; and in the test set four cities (one new); would you want the fourth parameter estimate to be mean(0, 0.1, -0.4) = -0.1?

Comment: When you split your dataset to "test" and "train" maybe one of the cities has few observations and it happens that all of those go to the "test" set. Then after building your model and you try to predict, your model will break when it sees that city and won't recognise it. So, you have to make sure that this city has a good split in test and train sets. Of course, in real-life, when your model is in production, a completely new city might come up. Then the model will definitely break, but you can "catch" that and return another value in that case. But this is outside the model.

Comment: @SamThomas yes that is what I want. Is there a way to tell GLM to do this?

Comment: @AntoniosK unfortunately that is not really an option for me. It is very important I do not have any lookahead bias and as I am splitting on a date, if all observations of a city happen to be in the test set, I cannot pick  some of them for the training set.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'll just clarify that what I said before is that the "statistical" glm model will break as it won't recognise the city name. The model as a whole process that you've set up to predict could handle those cases with some extra filtering. I don't think that you can solve that within glm unless you (carefully) create some "fake" data with city name "unknown" and every new city get's that name which will be then recognised by your glm model.

Comment: one possibility would be to use a mixed model (`lme4`) and use `allow.new.levels=TRUE` when predicting ...

Comment: That's interesting @BenBolker. Haven't had the chance to use something like that yet. I'll have a look.

Comment: Another way would be to have model A (the one you mentioned) and model B (like A but without variable "city"). Then when a new case comes up you have a process that spots whether there's a city not recognised by model A and then sends that case to model B for prediction.

Comment: @AntoniosK That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: I hope your model doesn't have any more variables like that. Otherwise you might need to build some more alternative models. That's what I've done in the past. Also, keep in mind that continuous variables will never break your model in that way, but be careful of extrapolations. ie a model that was built using an input variable "weight (in kg)" with range [50kg,80kg] might lead to bad prediction if a new case has weight = 115kg. But, it's a slightly different issue and not what you initially asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Still pretty ugly, but I think it's a bit more general than your code.  Let me know if it misses the mark and I can modify or delete.

```
# dummy data
set.seed(321)
daf_train <- data.frame(x = runif(100, min=10, max=50), 
                        y = runif(100), 
                        city = sample(c("city1", "city2", "city3"), size=100, replace=TRUE))

set.seed(321)
daf_test <- data.frame(x = runif(30, min=10, max=50),
                       y = runif(30),
                       city = sample(c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4"), size=30, replace=TRUE))

daf_train$city <- factor(daf_train$city, levels=levels(daf_test$city))


# cities in test set but not train set
(newcity <- sort(unique(daf_test$city))[!sort(unique(daf_test$city)) %in% unique(daf_train$city)])
[1] city4
Levels: city1 city2 city3 city4

# fit model with city1, city2, city3
xreg <- cbind(x=daf_train$x, model.matrix(~ 0 + city, data=daf_train))

mylogit = glm(y ~ xreg, data=daf_train, family=binomial(link='logit'))

newxreg <- cbind(x=daf_test$x, model.matrix(~ 0 + city, data=daf_test))

# mean of city coefficients
if (length(newcity) > 0) {

  # coefficients from model
  citycoef <- coef(mylogit)[grepl("city", names(coef(mylogit)))]

  # calculate coefficient for new city(cities)
  citycoef_offset <- mean(citycoef, na.rm=TRUE)

  # repeat for all new cities
  citycoef[is.na(citycoef)] <- citycoef_offset 

  # center coefficients
  citycoef <- scale(citycoef, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)[, 1]

  # replace city coefficients from model
  modelcoef <- coef(mylogit)

  # add offset to intercept
  modelcoef[["(Intercept)"]] <- modelcoef[["(Intercept)"]] + citycoef_offset

  # all new coefficients
  modelcoef[match(names(citycoef), names(modelcoef))] <- citycoef

  # Beta0 + Beta1x...
  pcoef <- modelcoef[["(Intercept)"]] + 
    newxreg %*%
    modelcoef[!names(modelcoef) == "(Intercept)"]

  #predicted response
  predictions <- unlist(lapply(pcoef, function(x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))))


} else {
  predictions <- predict(mylogit, daf_test, type="response")
}
```